# python csv - print values of CSV if column 1 and column 2 have a certain value

Tags: python, csv

I have bookings CSV file with the following headings:
First Name, Last Name, Date of booking, Subject, Lesson Period, Class Size

I wish to read the CSV file, and only print the lines where Date of booking is "(certain value)" and lesson period is "(certain value")

So far, my code is:

```
check_date = "11/01/2019"
check_period = "Lesson 3"

with open("Bookings.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    header = next(reader)
    found = False
    for line in reader:
        if line[2] == check_date and line[4] == check_period:
            for line in reader:
                print(line)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        print("No bookings for", check_date, " ", check_period)
```

However, instead of outputting the rows where date is "11/01/2019" and lesson period is "Lesson 3" - it is instead printing the first row with this criteria, ignoring the rest, and printing the next line after this.

Screen shot below :
(showing code, output, and CSV example)

[Code Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQARc.png)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For line in reader inside a for line in reader so double access of your iterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting `break` inside `if` statement. With `break` you stop iterating through the list once you find the suitable row

Answer (score 1):

your issue is in the following part:

```
if line[2] == check_date and line[4] == check_period:
            for line in reader:
                print(line)
```

remove `for line in reader:`

you are trying to keep looping on your data without further checks and that also screws up your outer loop

and as mentioned by asmox, also remove the `break` statement

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to make this scale-able is to the use the popular '.csv' library pandas.  Within it, there are several ways to check a .csv file without looping through all the rows. Additionally, it works exceptionally well with extremely large .csv files should that become an issue for you in this.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
#Assign csv_file to variable names
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
name_csv = 'Bookings.csv'

check_date = "11/1/2019"
check_period = "Lesson 3"

#Read CSV into Pandas format called a DataFrame
csv_path = os.path.join(dir_path,name_csv)
DFAll = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csv_path)

#Check DataFrame with a Boolean qualifiers that return True if check_date 
#AND check_period are found in each column. 
#Then select only True rows from the .csv DataFrame

DFCheckedDates=DFAll[DFAll['Date'].str.match(check_date) & \
DFAll['Period'].str.match(check_period)]

#Return Rows were the conditions are both true
print(DFCheckedDates)
```

I hope this helped you. It may seem a bit excessive considering your .csv of 5 rows, but Pandas is a very versatile and useful library when working extensively with .csv files and has simple logic that allows for limiting the number of loops in a program.